# Make HTML5 canvas responsive to hover events

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I am drawing HTML5 canvas charts using the following code:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

var ctx =  $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200,200,scaleAnimation * doughnutRadius,cumulativeAngle,cumulativeAngle + segmentAngle,false);
ctx.arc(width/2,height/2,scaleAnimation * cutoutRadius,cumulativeAngle + segmentAngle,cumulativeAngle,true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = data[i].color;
ctx.fill();
cumulativeAngle += segmentAngle;
```

I haven't included all variable declarations here as they are not required. This essentially makes a doughnut chart. I want to make the chart responsive like the chart made with morris.js [here](http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?javascript,live).

That is on hovering over the various segments the value and labels are shown. The jsbin example has a different implementation. Can the same be done when using HTML5 canvas element?

Comment: Canvas does not provide that build-in - but of course you can read the mouse coordinates, and then compute yourself which "element" you painted to the canvas the cursor would be over.

Comment: Would that be advisable? In terms of performance or should I work towards a different implementation?

Comment: Have you tried CanvasEngine? http://canvasengine.net/